# POST value to cgi file but not update the web page

Tags: javascript, python, html, post, cgi

I have a web page with a switch (html & CSS) and a toggle function (JS) which changes the appearance of the switch as it is clicked. The toggle function has a 'standby' variable which tracks the status of the switch. 
I also have a form (JS) which POSTs the value of standby to a cgi script (python) which will control some lights. That all works!
Except, I do not want the cgi file to respond with a new web page or even reload the current web page - I'd like to keep the page as it is - which does not seem possible with cgi!
I'm guessing cgi is the wrong approach (& this is another dumb question!)
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You're looking for ajax  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers - I used JQuery and ajax as suggested and it has worked for me - simple when you know how! '$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/cgi-bin/hello.py",
      data: {status: standby}
    });'

Answer (score 1):

You can send your Form using Ajax. The easiest way is to use Jquery.

Here is a nice tutorial:
http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to make your request asynchronously using JavaScript.

Have a look at the [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or use a wrapper function like [jQuery’s $.ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (especially if you want to support older browsers).

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713078/1387396) for an example of how to do a POST request using the XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers - I appreciate you putting me on the right track. I used JQuery and ajax as suggested and it is working - simple when you know how!

This is in index.html:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cgi-bin/standby.py",
    data: {status: standby}
});
```

and in standby.py:

```
 data = cgi.FieldStorage() 
 data = data["status"].value
```